# Recomended approach to selecting memory for docker container running on an EC2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

What is the best practice to select memory size for a container running on an ec2?
My ec2 has 8gig of ram. It runs 2 containers.
PHP container
NGINX container

The NGINX container is set to 512 Mb.
How large is the recommendation to make the PHP container? It was set by some sort of default to 2 gigs, I want to make it 6gigs but was interested to hear what the recommendations are?

The basis for this question is that our container ran out of memory, and died. I believe we can alleviate this by upping the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to set memory limits is based on monitored metrics for memory usage. If you don't have metrics, then increase in increments and observe. Leave enough memory, say 1-2G, for the operating system itself.

Side note: Setup the container to auto restart via `--restart=always`, so even if the container is OOMKilled the app is restarted and continues to function.